# Opening new window for printing in JavaScript and Setting IE Compatibility Mode

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to print content of some div. To do so, I open new window in browser, fill it with content and then call print() method which opens printer options. Everything works great in every browser I tested except the IE, which sets Document mode to IE7 and breaks all styling.

I tried to set Compatibility Mode to IE8, but without success.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

Still saying it's forced by intranet compatibility settings, which I cannot change.

Here is how I open new window:

```
function printDiv() {
        var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=768,width=1366,resizable=no,scrollbars=auto');
        mywindow.document.write('<!DOCTYPE html>');
        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />')
        mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/URSPrintStyle.css" type="text/css" />');
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        mywindow.document.write('<div class="arp-container">')
        mywindow.document.write(document.getElementById('printableArea').innerHTML);
        mywindow.document.write('</div></body></html>');

        mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/

        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();

    }
```

In summary, is there a way to force compatibility with IE8 in new window opened by javascript?